# EXEC_BAD_ACCESS application crash in iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am newbie to iPhone development and have made a demo for learning purpose,I recently getting an exception at a code line as below,My application is crashing every time at this code line,Please help me to solve this,pls

```
 operation = [[CustomOperation alloc] initWithTarget:appDelegate 
                                            selector:@selector(saveTextOffline:) 
                                            object:[[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:self.selectedTripId,@"tripId",appDelegate.account.uniqueId,@"tripperId",YES,@"isNew", nil]];
```

Comment: Do you have an error in the debugger?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The tags you were using are not appropritate for this question. Please review [What are tags, and how should I use them?](//stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Comment: @Larme-No any error,my application is crashed at this line.

Comment: @JanGreve-Thank you so much ,+1 for best answer and comment,keep it up bro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot just put a primitive type such as `YES` (a `BOOL`) into a dictionary. If you want to put it there, put it as `@YES` (a `NSNumber` instance).

If you put a `YES` there, the dictionary tries to read `YES` as an object memory address. The value of `YES` is `1` and you cannot access memory with value `1`.

Answer (score 0):

EXEC_BAD_ACCESS come mostly when one of your object's has been deleted (or set to be null). I recommend, to set a breakpoint just before the line where it happens and doublecheck every object if they are nil.

Comment: Thank you for quick reply,I have checked and "operation" says its nill.

Comment: Yes, operation can be nil, before you initialize it with the right side of you statement written above. Check the objects in the right side of the equal sign.

Comment: i have checked `2016-02-04 16:11:49.897 Lets Trip It[2040:60b] ====trip id=====1208
2016-02-04 16:11:58.241 Lets Trip It[2040:60b] ====uniqueid=====454`both are not nil,so can you please tell me which can be nil?

Comment: Maybe this? self.selectedTripId

Comment: ahh..no.i have checked self.selectedTripId and appDelegate.account.uniqueId,both are not nil,